# Convert a 'login.php' page with form and error checking into a dropdown login instead

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, authentication

I've a login.php page that has a small form and a reasonable amount of php error control / validation.

There are two items in my header, one for login and one for register.  As of now they both redirect the user to the next page where they can login etc.

I recently read an article about improving user experience and using a jquery drop down login box would help with this.

[This is the type of thing I'm after](http://www.red-team-design.com/simple-and-effective-dropdown-login-box)

I wanted advice before I started hacking perfectly good code apart.  I'd like to keep the form style that I have, all the validation and all the php as it is.

Is it simply a case of putting the code from my login.php into my header include and then modifying the css to display what is visible?

Many thanks in advance.

PS, some may suggest I try first and then ask but I lost 4 hours work yesterday because I didn't ask for advice first :)

EDIT: 
So, I just copied and edited the code slightlyt so that the login form appears in my header, validation is still working, login still works so I guess it is just the css / jquery that needs to be worked on for this to work

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create the form inside the dropdown, and send the input to `login.php`. Something like:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

When a user submits the form, the data is sent to `login.php`, that will perform validation and will then redirect the user to the corresponding page.

So just copy the form.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I've done, I just need the css and jquery side of things to hide the login until a user clicks etc.

Comment: If you are developing the site you may be interested in Bootstrap. Dropdowns, popups, popovers and tons of styles.

Comment: Bootstrap does look great but I've done too much now to try and convert it, and I quite like doing things the hard way :)